# Javascript redirect to page and append text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a forum that you can filter by 'category1', 'category2', or 'all'

Now I have a dropdown that has only those three options.
With javascript/jquery I'm doing this:

```
$('#dropdown').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#dropdown').val() == 'category1') {
        window.location.href += "/cat1";
    } else if ($('#dropdown').val() == 'category2') {
        window.location.href += "/cat2";
    } else {
        window.location.replace(window.location.href);
    }
});
```

The problem with the code above is that the first change goes correctly to say: "website/foo/bar/cat1"
But when I change the dropdown again to cat2 it goes to this and fails:
"website/foo/bar/cat1/cat2"

Is there anyway I can keep the same URL everytime I change the dropdown value?
Theres a catch though. "website/foo/bar/" has "bar" which can actually be anything such as this: "website/foo/something/" or "website/foo/else/"

Comment: Just remove the `+=` and use relative urls

Comment: Or try to use query parameters

Answer (score 0):

When you add to the url like this += you are appending to the existing url.

```
var url = "http://example.com/foo/bar/"
$('#dropdown').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#dropdown').val() == 'category1') {
        window.location.href = url + "cat1";
    } else if ($('#dropdown').val() == 'category2') {
        window.location.href = url + "cat2";
    } else {
        window.location.replace(window.location.href);
    }
});
```